# CUDA texture memory with floating point co-ordinates

Tags: cuda, textures, linear-interpolation

Is it possible to assign value to a texture memory, for a non-integer co-ordinate?

i.e. assume we have a 1 Dimensional texture memory array. I understand we can allocate array elements at integer co-ordinates. We can then READ values at fractional co-ordinates, using linear interpolation.

My question is: does CUDA allow the programmer to WRITE values to fractional co-ordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: No - of course not - that's the whole point of doing interpolation when you read from a non-integer coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to write to fractional coordinates. There would be nowhere for the hardware to store the new values. Even though you can read with linear interpolation, the values between which interpolation is being performed can only be stored at integer locations in memory.

One way to implement this might be to write a kernel that reads your initial array of values and creates a higher resolution array with interpolated values. Then, you write your new values in this new array at the integer locations that are closest to the ones you actually want to write to.